# How to integrate additional website to ERPNext server

Tags: php, python, erpnext

The server is running Ubuntu 14.04 and as a VM.

I have downloaded the ERPNext VM from the website and it seems to be working fine. Since ERPNext's calendar is not optimised for managing clinic appointments I have decided to integrate it with Easy Appointments which is an open source web based appointment management system. I am having trouble adding the website to apache so that it can host it.

I tried:

- Adding a Virtual Host that hosts the Easy Appointments website on a different port by adding a conf file to available websites
- Adding a "Listen" line to the ports.conf file.
- Configuring sites-enabled files.

Note that I have successfully managed to get Easy Appointments working fine on another VM that doesn't have ERPNext installed. There just seems to be an issue with ERPNext. Also I don't seem to be able to find the website configuration for ERPNext in the usual /etc/Apache2 directory.

Please advise on how I can do this.

Comment: The website configuration for ERPNext will be under your `sites` folder, in the corresponding `site`.

Comment: I was looking for the corresponding apache2 config files. Are they also in the sites folder? If yes, what are the filenames?

Comment: The config files should be present under the `config` folder under your bench path. Filenames should be stratight forward, e.g. `nginx.conf`.